# Getting distinct values using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have two tables 2017 and 2018. Both the tables have the same columns but the values are different. I want to get distinct values of each column and I want to ensure that all unique column in 2018 present in 2017. I have more than 100 columns in each table. I have tried the below query using cursor. And the result will be stored in other table called 'RESULT_MINUS'

```
DECLARE
   COL         VARCHAR2 (200);
   OUTRECORD   VARCHAR2 (200);

   CURSOR COLUMN_NM
   IS
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM all_tab_columns
       WHERE     table_name = 'COMPARE_2018_P1'


   CURSOR DIFFERENCE
   IS
      SELECT OUTRECORD
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL
                FROM COMPARE_2018_P1
              MINUS
              SELECT DISTINCT COL
                FROM COMPARE_2017_P1);
BEGIN
   OPEN COLUMN_NM;

   LOOP
      FETCH COLUMN_NM INTO COL;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (COL);

      OPEN DIFFERENCE;

      LOOP
         FETCH DIFFERENCE INTO OUTRECORD;

         INSERT INTO RESULT_MINUS
              VALUES ('B001',
                      'COMPARE',
                      '2018',
                      COL,
                      OUTRECORD,
                      'NOT PRESENT IN 2017');
                      COMMIT;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE DIFFERENCE;
       END LOOP;

       CLOSE COLUMN_NM;

    END;
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired output.  (3) Ask a question.  For instance, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Why do you have different tables for different years?

Comment: I am using oracle database

Comment: Its an report for 2 years @ jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a cursor in the inner loop for inserting the differences?  Just do:

```
INSERT INTO RESULT_MINUS ( . . . ) -- always include the columns
    SELECT 'B001', 'COMPARE', '2018', 'COL', COL, 'NOT PRESENT IN 2017'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL
          FROM COMPARE_2018_P1
          MINUS
          SELECT DISTINCT COL
          FROM COMPARE_2017_P1
         ) c;
```

As for looping over the columns in the table, that is a reasonable use of a cursor.

Your code doesn't work because the `DIFFERENCE` cursor needs to be defined in the inner loop.  But it is not needed at all.

Comment: But  I need to compare distinct values of each and every column. So I thought of using cursor

Comment: @mano . . . You can  use the cursor for the *columns*.  You don't need a cursor for the *values*.

Comment: But when I am passing the column to the difference cursor its not working

Comment: Use the above query instead of the difference cursor.  You may need to use dynamic sql (`execute immediate`) to put the column name in.

Comment: I want to store the result of that query in another table

Comment: If I get more than one record in the minus query ,the insert statement will not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `CURSOR` logic, you must define the `DIFFERNECE`cursor dynamically (substituting the column name).

change

```
OPEN DIFFERENCE;
```

for

```
OPEN FOR
  'SELECT OUTRECORD
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ' || COL ||
           ' FROM COMPARE_2018_P1
          MINUS
          SELECT DISTINCT ' || COL ||
           ' FROM COMPARE_2017_P1)';
```

and remove the definition of the cursor.

But of course the approach using dynamic insert from other answer is prefereble due to a better performence.